# How to preload an angular route and switch only when the route has been successfully loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am currently developing an administrative dashboard for my place of work using the [BlurAdmin](https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin) template. While this template contains many great features and great functionality, I found that this dashboard was not quite optimized for my use case. The dashboard that I am developing is completely based on a RESTful API built separately by one of my colleagues. Every page loads in its data through this API using AJAX and have found that most of the time, the page shows up before the API completes. This means that things just sporadically show up as the calls complete. In order to make for a smoother UI experience, I have began working on a solution for this.

**Current Solution**
While a route is being loading, a rootScope variable `$isLoading` is set to true which displays a loading overlay stretched over the page. In order to determine completion, I watch `$http.pendingRequests.length` until it is equal to 0 which tells me that the page has loaded successfully (based solely on http calls).

**Desired Solution**
While a route is being loaded, I would like the page not to change but instead utilize a top-bar loader and only when the page is loaded, should the routes change.

The routing is currently done by BlurAdmin using the [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/) module and the view is always instantly displayed by the `ui-view` directive.

My question then is: How do I preload an angular route into a hidden view while it builds, and only once I detect that all API calls have completed on this new route, should the hidden view switch to the visible view and the old visible view be removed?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by using a [resolve](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/hellosolarsystem#resolve-data) on your state declaration. The basic idea would be to call your API from your resolve functions on the relevant state declarations. If you return promises from these functions the state will not be entered until the promises are all resolved. The values will then be bound into your component.

To show the spinner/loading bar on state transitions you could register a [Transition Hook](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks) for 2 events: `onStart` and `onFinish`. Inside your `onStart` hook set some state on a service. Let's say `isTransitioning = true;`. Inside your `onFinish` hook, set this to false. Your spinner component could then watch this state and show itself when appropriate.

Comment: This is a solution I have also looked into. The problem is that my API is loaded in controllers for different directives. For example, the dashboard home contains variable components that each have their own controllers that control the API loading in. As far as i can tell, resolves can only link to the controller that is use in the global state.

Comment: So you want to block transitioning until all of those directives on the page have their data? The only way I can think of doing this, is to use resolves like we discussed to bind all the required data into a container component which then passes in the relevant data to the child components through bindings. This means that the child components do not fetch their own data - they are only responsible for rendering their data.

Comment: Also, just to say - I actually prefer the UX of showing loading states for each individual component as it fetches its data. Lets me know what to expect when the page loads :)